# Newbie: query based on string - greater than x time

Tags: splunk

We are doing performance monitoring on our servers and the logging is trapping records where the end of the record has a string of:

```
execution time: X ms
```

(where X is a number).

I'm trying to write a query to show anything greater than 5 ms.

I've searched on the forums and been going through documentation and search tips but it seems my searches aren't well thought out and nothing I've found is relevant.

Any assistance or pointing and laughing is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I knew that as soon as I posted, i'd find my answer.  For those curious:

```
index=foo sourcetype=foo_log "execution time" |rex field=_raw "execution time: (?<perftime>.*) ms" | bin _time span=5m | search (perftime > 5)
```

It may not be totally correct but I'm getting the record matches that I need. If there is a better way, feel free to correct me.